# Why am I not getting a match request in Metal Slug Defense?

Tags: ios, android, metal-slugs-defense

I'm on an iPhone and my friend is on an Android device. Why can't I find my friend's match request in Metal Slug Defense?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Metal Slug Defense does not support cross-platform multiplayer.  In order to play with your friend, you'll both need to be using the same type of device.